# ion-tabs isn't shown when loaded through ion-nav-view?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I made a simple experiment to load a page with ion-tabs in index.html with ion-nav-view but it didn't show anything in the browser preview but if I put the ion-tabs straightly without ion-nav-view in the page, its shown normally. However, if I use my phone browser, the tab is shown and okay too even if I use ion-nav-view. I'm using Ionic 2.2

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" >
        <ion-nav-view class="has-header has-footer"></ion-nav-view> 
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('tab_test', {
         url: '/tabtest',
         templateUrl: 'templates/tab_test.html'
     })
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabtest');
})
```

tab_test.html:

```
<ion-tabs id="tab_main">
   <ion-tab title="FAQ" ui-sref="home_test.faq">
       <ion-nav-view name="faq"></ion-nav-view>
   </ion-tab>
   <ion-tab title="Komplain" ui-sref="home_test.komplain">
       <ion-nav-view name="komplain"></ion-nav-view>
   </ion-tab>
   <ion-tab title="Saran" ui-sref="home_test.saran">
       <ion-nav-view name="saran"></ion-nav-view>
   </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: What is the ionic version in your `package.json`? This seems to me Ionic v1 instead of v2

Comment: Ionic 2.2, I followed the example in learning Ionic, the index.html was generated by the template

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue my self, the problem is if we used both has-header and has-footer in ion-nav-view, ion-tabs wouldn't be rendered... omg... I spent 1 whole day to resolved this issue and I believe that more problem will come in the future if I use Ionic.

```
<ion-nav-view class="has-header has-footer"></ion-nav-view>
```